# Dependency on local file creation

Tags: terraform

I am setting up an EKS cluster with Terraform following the example https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-eks/blob/master/aws_auth.tf and I now have two Terraform files:

kubeconfig.tf

```
resource "local_file" "kubeconfig" {
  content  = "${data.template_file.kubeconfig.rendered}"
  filename = "tmp/kubeconfig"
}

data "template_file" "kubeconfig" {
  template = "${file("template/kubeconfig.tpl")}"
...
}
```

aws-auth.tf

```
resource "null_resource" "update_config_map_aws_auth" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "kubectl apply -f tmp/config-map-aws-auth_${var.cluster-name}.yaml --kubeconfig /tmp/kubeconfig"
  }

  ...
 }
```

When I run this the local-exec command fails with

> Output: error: stat tmp/kubeconfig: no such file or directory

On a second run it succeeds. I think that the file is created after local-exec tries to use it and local-exec should depend on the file resource. So I try to express the dependency by using interpolation (implicit dependency) like this:

```
resource "null_resource" "update_config_map_aws_auth" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "kubectl apply -f tmp/config-map-aws-auth_${var.cluster-name}.yaml --kubeconfig ${resource.local_file.kubeconfig.filename}"
  }
```

But this always gives me

> Error: resource 'null_resource.update_config_map_aws_auth' provisioner
>   local-exec (#1): unknown resource 'resource.local_file' referenced in
>   variable resource.local_file.kubeconfig.filename

Comment: You don't need the `resource.` part when using the interpolation in the last code block. When Terraform first started it just had resources so you don't need to say that something's a resource as that was the only case. They then added modules and data sources which required some differentiation in the naming so these get `module.` and `data.` so Terraform can tell resources and data sources etc apart.

Comment: Thanks! That worked.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need the `resource.` part when using the interpolation in the last code block.

When Terraform first started it just had resources so you don't need to say that something's a resource as that was the only case. They then added modules and data sources which required some differentiation in the naming so these get `module.` and `data.` so Terraform can tell resources and data sources etc apart.

So you probably want something like this:

```
resource "local_file" "kubeconfig" {
  content  = "${data.template_file.kubeconfig.rendered}"
  filename = "tmp/kubeconfig"
}

data "template_file" "kubeconfig" {
  template = "${file("template/kubeconfig.tpl")}"
  ...
}

resource "null_resource" "update_config_map_aws_auth" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "kubectl apply -f tmp/config-map-aws-auth_${var.cluster-name}.yaml --kubeconfig ${local_file.kubeconfig.filename}"
  }
}
```